# Javascript popup doesn't work on next page pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination

I have build a project like data view by using PHP and Javascript. on my page, it have a user table by using pagination. Every row have delete button. When I click that button on first page, its work properly. when I click delete button at every row on next page, looks like popup stop working anymore. below is my code:

Javascript for run the popup:

```js
$(".mb-control").on("click",function(){
        var box = $($(this).data("box"));
        if(box.length > 0){
            box.toggleClass("open");

            var sound = box.data("sound");

            if(sound === 'alert')
                playAudio('alert');

            if(sound === 'fail')
                playAudio('fail');

        }        
        return false;
    });
    $(".mb-control-close").on("click",function(){
       $(this).parents(".message-box").removeClass("open");
       return false;
    });
```

HTML in PHP script for delete button (in while function- $i is variable for unique id every row)

```html
<?php

echo "<td>
 
 <button class='btn btn-warning mb-control btn-sm' href='./function/liststaff.remove.php?remove=".$getdata['username']."' data-box='#message-box-warning".$i."'>Remove <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></i></button></a>
                
 <div class='message-box message-box-warning animated fadeIn' id='message-box-warning".$i."'>
 <div class='mb-container'>
 <div class='mb-middle'>
 <div class='mb-title'><span class='fa fa-warning'></span> Warning</div>
 <div class='mb-content'>
 <p>Are you sure want to delete user  <strong>".$getdata['username']." </strong>?.</p>                  
 </div>
 <div class='mb-footer'>
 <div class='pull-right'>
 <a href='index.php?delete=".$getdata['id']."' class='btn btn-success btn-lg'>Yes</a>
 <button class='btn btn-default btn-lg mb-control-close'>No</button>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
                
 </td>";

?>
```

please help.

Comment: Change `var box = $($(this).data("box"));` to `var box = $(this).data("box");`

Comment: it same. still not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to bind click event on dynamically created element as below for second page BUTTONS with class name **mb-control** not exist on DOM so the event is attached only to existing elements.

Hope it'll help you.

```
 $("body").on("click",".mb-control-close",function(){
       $(this).parents(".message-box").removeClass("open");
       return false;
    });

$("body").on("click",".mb-control",function(){
        var box = $($(this).data("box"));
        if(box.length > 0){
            box.toggleClass("open");

            var sound = box.data("sound");

            if(sound === 'alert')
                playAudio('alert');

            if(sound === 'fail')
                playAudio('fail');

        }        
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: still not work. by the way for pagination i using DataTables version 1.10.9 from DataTables.net

Comment: have do it again but still same.

Comment: By the way when i put that Javascript on same file, its will work on next page but not work on first page. when i put that Javascript on other file, first page going to working propely but on next page stop working. when i put that Javascript on duo page(same and other file), popup on first page stop working. I dont know what should do.

Comment: @KhalilIsmail check your console what it says when you click remove button on seconds page?

Comment: thanks , after i clear my cache on my browser, looks like its working now by using your code.

Comment: @KhalilIsmail Ohh that's cool you are always welcome please marked as answer if you find it'll work for you and for future references as well.. you want to know how to do that please check [mark as answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2):

I think your paginated rows containing buttons are not able to bind to click event since they are created dynmaically:

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','.mb-control-close', function (event) {
        $(this).parents(".message-box").removeClass("open");
           return false;
    });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzk5880j/)

Comment: @KhalilIsmail check the link I had posted in the answer and do an `alert` to see if you can alert or not

Comment: @KhalilIsmail always reload a browser page using ctlr+F5 it loads a fresh copy.

Answer (score 1):

For event binding on dynamic content, direct events should not be used, use delegated events instead. Take a look [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).